# Trying to make my BigCartel product page look better but there is a problem with where the display of the price is

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm trying to figure how to move the price on the product page to be on top of the description of the product. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSLfi.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD5a1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible scenario how this layout is build and where the price should be to get what you want.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
}

h1 {
text-align:center;
}

.product-display {
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
gap:1rem;
}

.media {
width:50%;
}

img {
width:100%;
}

.description {
width:50%;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>THE GARAGE STICKER</h1>

  <!-- Current Position could be here -->
  <div class="price">
    <span>$2.00</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-display">
  
    <div class="media">
      <!-- Current Position could be also here -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" width="400" height="400"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="description">
      <!-- The "price" Container should be here -->
      <span>OG design concept</span>
      <span>Size: 3" x 2.24"</span>
      <button type="button">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Big Cartel using a different way of writing the code, I'll try to provide a picture